# tengo un problema con ffmpeg, uniendo audio y video(Python)

Tags: python

intente de todas maneras unir el audio y el video, pero siempre me tira ese error. porfavor si alguien sabes me da una mano.
desde ya muchas gracias

> CODE

```
import ffmpeg

input_video = ffmpeg.input('Paramore Still Into You [OFFICIAL VIDEO].mp4')

input_audio = ffmpeg.input('Paramore Still Into You [OFFICIAL VIDEO].webm')

ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output('finished_video.mp4').run()
```

> ERROR

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\victo\workspace\youtube\tomas\intento2.py", line 7, in <module>
    ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output('finished_video.mp4').run()
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```